# Keeping two jquery UI tabs in sync

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, wordpress, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to keep two jquery UI tabs in sync. You can see the tabs [here](http://nec24.com/) on the homepage. Basically, when clicked on Houston, the other Houston tab should be clicked, and same for Austin.

Here is what I did (I have now removed the code due to it being very slow):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a[href='#houston']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("a[href='#houston_locations']", ".wp-tabs").click();
    });

    jQuery("a[href='#austin']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("a[href='#austin-3']", ".wp-tabs").click();
    });

    jQuery("a[href='#houston_locations']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("a[href='#houston']", ".wp-tabs").click();
    });

    jQuery("a[href='#austin-3']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("a[href='#austin']", ".wp-tabs").click();
    });
});
```

My code above works; however it's very slow, and also gives me an error in the console for "too much recursion".

Can anybody else offer a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you can try with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("a[href='#houston']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
    $("a[href='#houston_locations']", ".wp-tabs").trigger("click");
});

jQuery("a[href='#austin']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("a[href='#austin-3']", ".wp-tabs").trigger("click");
});

jQuery("a[href='#houston_locations']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("a[href='#houston']", ".wp-tabs").trigger("click");
});

jQuery("a[href='#austin-3']", ".wp-tabs").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("a[href='#austin']", ".wp-tabs").trigger("click");
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks, your suggested approach works too. I just don't know why it's being slow and why it's giving me this error every time I click on a tab: "too much recursion"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click one of the Houston tabs it fires the click event of the second Houston tab, which fires the click event of the first Houston tab, which fires the click even of the second Houston tab, and so on. This is what your error console is referring to by "too much recursion" - as this will continue to happen until the browser decides it has had enough (which is why it is running slow).

To solve this problem, I would separate the main click methods for each tab into separate functions, and call both those functions within each click event.

Hope that helps